# Recover lost vault

Tags: fallout-shelter

I recently deleted fallout shelter from my Android phone and I was wondering how I recovered my account. I saved it to cloud but when I downloaded it there was no game there. Any one help?

Answer (score 4):

Instructions from Bethesda's forum:

> You can restore your saved Fallout ShelterVault from the cloud by
>   following the steps below:
>
> - Launch Fallout Shelter on your Android or iOS device.
> - Navigate to the Vault List from the main menu.
> - Select the Cloud checkbox that corresponds to the save slot the vault was originally saved from.
>
>   - If a vault save file exists, you will recieve a message prompt stating that there is a save conflict.
> - You will then be able to restore the vault save file to your device by selecting the appropriate cloud save file.
>
> The save file will then download to your device and be ready to play.

[Source](http://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/31236/~/how-do-i-restore-a-saved-fallout-shelter-vault-from-the-cloud%3F)